# CSS: Div and Argument Selectors

Tags: python, css

I have the following structure,

```
<div class="main">
    <div id="son" class="well"></div>
    <div id="done" 
    data-ret="512,500"></div>
    </div>
```

How do I acess the data-ret argument inside div id done? For doing some web scraping.

Tried a couple of ways but don't seem to be able to stick it.

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by `access`?

Comment: @Kosh Very basically I need a css selector which gives me those values, I’m assembling a web crawler and needed that info.

Comment: CSS has no method of determining what the **value** of the attribute actually is as such. You can select based on a element *having* an attribute but NOT the value of the attribute *(unless you already know the value)* - in which case it compares a defined string against the value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `beautiful soup` library:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = '''<div class="main">
    <div id="son" class="well"></div>
    <div id="done" 
    data-ret="512,500"></div>
    </div>'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html,"lxml")
data_ret = soup.find("div",{'id':'done'})

print(data_ret['data-ret'])
```

O/P:

```
512,500
```

Comment: how would that work without beautiful soup? just in pure css? thanks!